# Scrbook subsubsections formatted like paragraphs

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs, scrbook

I'm using the scrbook class and would like to have subsubsections formatted exactly like paragraphs (like in the image). I tried to copy the `\paragraphformat` to overwrite the `\subsubsectionformat` but it doesn't do anything. I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=4]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\theparagraph\autodot\enskip}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Title of subsubsection} 

\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{Title of subsubsection} 

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either a negative value for `afterindent` and the default `runin=bysign`:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=bysign,% default
  afterskip=-1em
]{subsubsection}
```

or `runin=true`:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=true,
  afterskip=1em
]{subsubsection}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=4]{hyperref}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=true,
  afterskip=1em
]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Title of subsubsection} 
\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{Title of subsubsection} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]